# Multithreading with one JTextBox

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have some code here that causes an issue for me. I am creating an application that will change the humidity of a greenhouse and then put it in a JTextBox. I have two classes, one to change the humidity and another class that takes care of ambient humidity. The two classes share one text box and the problem is that sometimes two values get printed on one another. How can I do this so that the threads do not overlap with their text box input?

```
private class humidControl implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
                    screen.setField(String.valueOf(calc.getHumid()), 21);
                    Thread.sleep(1000*humidTime);
                    while(on == true) {
                    calc.changeHumid();
                    screen.setField(String.valueOf(calc.getHumid()), 21);
                    if(calc.getHumidifier())
                        screen.setField("Humidifier is on", 24);
                    else if (!calc.getHumidifier());
                        screen.setField("Humidifier is off", 24);
                    Thread.sleep(1000*humidTime);


            }

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
private class AmbientHumid implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
                    while(on == true) {
                    calc.ambientHumid();
                    screen.setField(String.valueOf(calc.getHumid()), 21);
                    Thread.sleep(1000*AhumidTime);

            }

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the same field? Shouldn't they have there own fields?

Comment: Also, swing's not thread safe, so you should never block the EDT or update the ui from outside the EDT

Comment: Both of them use the same variable and affect the same humidity value the humidity value is what is being updated into the text box.

Comment: But they are simultaneously displaying different values?  Wouldn't it be better to use two different fields?  Or at least only update them at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Never ever modify or access any Swing component from any thread other than the event dispatch thread. Swing components are NOT thread safe and are confined to the EDT. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` from other Threads. `SwingWorker` also comes in handy when having to do work off the EDT and then modify some Swing component in the end.

Comment: Or use a SwingWorker or Swing Timer based on needs ;)

Comment: What is a JTextBox by the way?

Comment: I don't know. I assume he meant JTextField. But even if it is a JTextBox from some library or an own wrapper around a JTextField (which has no setField method), as long as it is a Swing component, my answer holds true and the tag and class naming style suggests so.

Comment: I assume nothing, and hope and expect the OP to be precise in the description and display of his code and his problem.

Comment: Well, he said it is about a Swing component that he is updating from different threads and that is what I answered about. How that Swing component is named is unimportant for me to answer this question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, in the humid runnable, you output at 21 and the AmbientHumid outputs at 21 as well, i suggest outputting the AmbientHumid at, say 27, so the overlap won't occur.